# Not able to create Live CD

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, live-cd

I downloaded 12.04.1 on a Windows 7 machine. I burnt a DVD from the ISO image using Windows Disc Image Burner. I had 'verify disc' on.  The disc was created successfully with no errors. I was not able to use this disc for installing Ubuntu on another Windows 7 machine. I do not get the Welcome Screen on booting.

I find that on the disc I burnt, I do not find **bin, disc tree, programs directories and cdromupgrade, start.*, ubuntu* files**. I found the boot directory and WUBI executable file.  I tried downloading several times with the same result.  I had similar problem earlier with 11.04.

Can you please let me where the problem is?

Comment: What do you get after booting the machine with the LiveCD? What is your graphic card?

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS boot order?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that Booting from CD Drive is enable from BIOS. This will prevent Booting of CD at startup.In some Case you need to give First priority to CD Drive.